# ORA-01031(insufficient privilages) ORA-01501(create database failed) ORA-01100(database already mounted)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I tried to create a database in Oracle database 11g edition but it throws an error:

> ORA-01501:CREATE DATABASE failed

So I tried command `SQL>shut immediate;` but it also threw error:

> ORA-01031:Insufficient Privileges

What does this mean "database already mounted"?

Comment: You should post much more info than you did - database version, username you used to create the database (should be SYS as SYSDBA), exact command you issued, complete error message(s). The best option is to copy/paste the whole SQL*Plus session.

Comment: after logging in sql I gave command " create database db1; "                but it printed error ORA-01501 and ORA-01100

Comment: Which part of my previous comment did you not understand? By the way, did you - at least - read & follow Oracle documentation which instructs you how to create a database, or are you just typing what you think might do the job?

Answer (score 0):

"Database already mounted" means the database's control file is already opened within a running ORACLE instance.

The DBCA utility (not the `create database` statement directly) is the recommended way of creating a database in 11G:

(Below is the URL for 11GR1 - the URL may be different for 11GR2):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/create002.htm#ADMIN12479

If you're receiving ORA-1031 (insufficient privileges) when trying to shut down, make sure you are logged in as SYSDBA or SYSOPER, E.G.

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Answer (score 0):

In WINDOWS

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Services

Here I restarted the following services:

*OracleServiceXE

*OracleXEClrAgent

And Oracle database 11g edition started working normally again.
PS:Don't forget to restart the system